# Using Paging Query Attribute in .NET Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, odata, paging

I am trying to build an OData endpoint for a Table valued function in sql database. I must enable paging such that the page size value is taken from the web.config file.

I guess I must extend the EnableQuery attribute to do this, like:

```
public class EnablePagedQueryAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
{
    public EnablePagedQueryAttribute()
    {
        int myPageSizeFromWebConfig = 0;

        // Get value from web.config as you want:
        if (int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myPageSize"], out myPageSizeFromWebConfig))
        {
            this.PageSize = myPageSizeFromWebConfig;
        }
    }
}
```

I used the above class in my controller and instead of EnableQuery, I used EnablePagedQuery in the controller method but the queries are not working at all : $top, $select, none are working,

I guess there is something wrong in the this EnablePagedQuery extension because with EnableQuery all are working.

Also, **how could I check if indeed the page size has changed** ?

Answer (score 0):

The $select query will not work because when you use a method in the controller using ODataQueryOptions (to pick the options in the query), you can't use select as [it does not support select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.query.odataqueryoptions(v=vs.118).aspx). So, you must not try to compose $select in your query.

Also, to check if page size has changed an easy option is to set it to small values like 1,2 and check if your query response does indeed change.